# C/UNIX Interprocess communication sending a string with pipe

Tags: c, unix, time, pipe, ipc

I am writing a code in which children and parent should give time information to one other and the receiver should print it.When I find time on parent process and try to print it on parent process It works fine.But when I try to send it through a pipe it writes a line with weird question marks and a z letter.I commented the last line in case if someone tries to execute the code. SOrry for the messy code but I cannot fix it in my current keyboard.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>


void formatted_time(char* sender_name, char* receiver_name, char output[]);
void formatted_time(  char* sender_name ,  char* receiver_name, char output[])
{
  struct timeval tv;
  time_t nowtime;
  struct tm *nowtm;
char tmbuf[80];
  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  nowtime = tv.tv_sec;
  nowtm = localtime(&nowtime);
  strftime(tmbuf,80 , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
            nowtm);
  sprintf(output, "%s: Time at %s is %s.", receiver_name, sender_name,  tmbuf);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     char* parent="Parent";
     char* child1="Child1";
     char* child2="Child2";
    char result[80];
    char buffer[80];
    int firstchild,secondchild,read1,read2,read3;
    firstchild=fork();
        int mypipe[2];
    int mypipe2[2];
    int mypipe3[2];

        if(pipe(mypipe) == -1) {
          perror("Pipe failed");
          exit(1);
        }

        if(firstchild == 0)            //first child
        {
         close(mypipe[1]);    //Closing  the output  of pipe
    sleep(3);
    read1=read(mypipe[0],buffer,sizeof(buffer));    
     printf("%s\n",buffer);



        }else{
    secondchild=fork();        //Creating second child

        if(secondchild == 0)            //2nd child
        {

        sleep(6);


        }else{            //Parent
    close(mypipe[0]);     //Closing the input of pipe
    formatted_time(parent,child1,result);   
    write(mypipe[1],result,strlen(result)+1);
    //printf("%s\n",result);
```

Comment: Where do you `read` from the pipe? I don't see it anywhere in your code. Also, using `sleep` is a very crude way to try and synchronise the processes and is bound to break at some point.

Comment: I thought this wrote to the other end of the pipe. write(mypipe[1],result,strlen(result)+1);  .I might be wrong but thats how I learned it in the book

Comment: Yes, that is the `write` call, but where is the **`read`**?

Comment: Wow,I forgot to add it.But still it only writes a question mark.

Comment: Do you have strong terminating NUL char in place when you print?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you do a `fork` call **before** you create your pipe. So in fact you `read` reads nothing, and your `printf` prints garbage that was on the stack where `buffer` was allocated.

Here is your code fixed. I also added a `wait` call in the parent to avoid child printing to the console out of nowhere :)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void formatted_time(char *sender_name,char *receiver_name, char output[]) {
    struct timeval tv;
    time_t nowtime;
    struct tm *nowtm;
    char tmbuf[80];
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    nowtime = tv.tv_sec;
    nowtm = localtime(&nowtime);
    strftime(tmbuf,80, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", nowtm);
    sprintf(output, "%s: Time at %s is %s.", receiver_name, sender_name, tmbuf);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* parent="Parent";
    char* child1="Child1";
    char result[80];
    char buffer[80];
    int firstchild, secondchild, read1;

    int mypipe[2];

    if (pipe(mypipe) == -1) {
        perror("Pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    firstchild=fork();
    if (firstchild == 0) { // first child
        close(mypipe[1]); //Closing  the output  of pipe
        sleep(3);
        read1 = read(mypipe[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));    
        printf("%d %s\n", read1, buffer);
    } else {
        secondchild=fork(); //Creating second child
        if(secondchild == 0) { //2nd child
            sleep(6);
        } else { //Parent
            close(mypipe[0]); //Closing the input of pipe
            formatted_time(parent, child1, result); 
            int w;
            w = write(mypipe[1], result, strlen(result)+1);
            printf("%d bytes written\n", w);
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works.Also in my code I could transfer data between the second child and parent which corresponds with what you are saying.Read in the first child was not working but read in the second child was working.I have one more little question.How can I use an another pipe to pass info from child one to child two.And from child two to parent(like a cycle).I tried that with creating two different pipes and I made them wait 3 seconds before getting the time.But in the end all of the time values were same.

Comment: @JonathanPark: Creating two additional pipes (one for child1->child2 and second for child2->parent) should work. You should create them in the parent process.

Comment: As an example I will update the code in my post and add another pipe but it prints nothing.

Comment: Code which sends from child1 to child2 here: http://pastebin.com/siW2W2jP (has no error checking).

Comment: Yeah it works.Also same way I was able to use a 3rd pipe and merge it to the rest of my program which is not shown in here.You have been very helpful,thanks

Comment: Nice example code.  However, there are three return conditions from `fork()`  the posted answer fails to check for the third condition (the `fork()` failed condition)  And the example code is using 'sleep()` for synchronization.  A bad idea,  Suggest using a mutex for pipe syncing or/better use posix IPC or system V ipc.  The reason is that a pipe does not have any concept of a record (the date info) but the posix and system V do have the concept of a record,  making the communication very robust.

Comment: @user3629249: Well, the code is just OP's code witch some changes that make it works. Also, `sleep` is not used for synchronization. As you can read from the chit-chat above OP used it to "generate" different timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

You are forking the first child before you are creating the pipe. Thus, you create two distinct pipes: one in the parent and one in the child. Afterwards, if you read from the pipe created in the first child, the `read` returns 0, indicating that no data has been read. Thus, data in the buffer is invalid and the `printf` is prohibited. Always check the return code of API calls!

The user "nsilent22" already provided a good clean-up of your code. After adding 3 closing brackets `}` at the end to close all blocks, you have at least move the fork after creating the pipe:

```
firstchild=fork();
if (firstchild == 0) { // first child
```

And at the read call, you should check the return code:

```
  read1=read(mypipe[0],buffer,sizeof(buffer));
  if (read1 <= 0) {
    printf("read failed with code %d\n, ", read1);
  } else {
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
  }
```

Comment: This also seems correct and thanks for the warning.Before reading your post I succeed in passing the info from parent to second child with the same exact code I tried for the first child.So I figured that something was wrong with first child.This helped me understand easier